# need examples of different groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

I need examples of different groups having different properties, such as:

1. class 2 or 3
2. cyclic commutator
3. cyclic center
4. $Z(G)\le \Phi(G)$
5. redei group
6. $G=\langle aG',bG' \rangle $

and ...
Are there books or websites that have this kind of example?
because most books I read online are just filled with theorems and lemmas.

Comment: I read some algebra textbook some have afew example

Comment: Well, I think if you already have a few examples, why are you listing these classes of groups here, too? At least write down what examples you already have. Otherwise, helpful people will waste their time just finding stuff you already have. Not very polite!

Comment: The dihedral and quaternion groups of order 8 are both nilpiotent of class 2, both have cyclic centre, both have $Z(G) \le \Phi(G)$ (in fact they are equal), both have $G=\langle aG',bG'\rangle$! I don't know what a redie group is.

Comment: I'm not asking to give me example here. I'm asking if you know some book with this kind of examples. I need about 50 different group. I can't ask all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an online resource, you could have a look at this website:

http://ericmoorhouse.org/pub/bol/.

This is about the weaker (not *necessarily* associative) structure of some finite loops but, among these, you can search the isotopy classes of groups. For example

http://ericmoorhouse.org/pub/bol/htmlfiles8/8_5_2_0.html

or

http://ericmoorhouse.org/pub/bol/htmlfiles18/18_1_18_1.html.

Below each Cayley table you find several things like, e.g., the elements of the *centrum* (set of all elements of the group $G$ which commute with every element of $G$), the *order* of each element of $G$ and some other facts interesting for groups.